# Calculated field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a very simple problem but i am totally new in Tableau. So needs some help in solving this problem.

My Data Set contain

Year_Track_4,Year_Track_5,Year_Track_6,Year_Track_7,.... N
 Each Year_Track contain 1 /0 values. 1 means graduated and 0 means didnot graduated or failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J9CD.png)
y4     y5        N

1                8
0                5
1                6
0                1
1                2
1                5
1                7
1                8
        1        5

```
    0        7

    1        5

    1        8

    1        6

    1        1
```

So , I want to create a placeholder in Tableau or Calculated Field or parameter to select one YEAR and count number of graduated or didn't graduated.

I need to create the same for OverAll_0 and OverAll_1 as one Calculated field and it contains the value of 1 and 0 . So, that i can use the SUM(N) and and calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

I used IFF statement to solve this problem
IIF(Year_Track_4 = 0) then 'graduated in 4 year '
.......
......